# Matching string regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match data from strings like the following:

24.Legacy.S01E08.720p.HDTV.x264-AVS[rarbg]

Colony.S02E09.720p.HDTV.x264-FLEET[rarbg]

- 24.Legacy (everything before S01E08)
- S => 01
- E => 08
- 720p.HDTV.x264 (everything between S01E08 and -)
- AVS (everything between - en [)
- rarbg (everything between [])

The following test almost works but needs some tweaks:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(.*?).S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+).(.*?)(.*?)[(.*?)]/s',
    $download,
    $posts,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

Comment: Can you comment on what is going wrong with your current regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a part is optional just add some `( )` around it and a `?` behind it, like this

```
//         NAME  SEASON   EPISOE   MEDIUM  OPTIONS
$regex = '/(.+)\.S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)\.(.+)(\[(.+)\])?/i';
```

but watch out for changing `$match` indexes

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24.Legacy.S01E08.720p.HDTV.x264-AVS[rarbg]
    [1] => 24.Legacy
    [2] => 01
    [3] => 08
    [4] => 720p.HDTV.x264-AVS
    [5] => [rarbg]
    [6] => rarbg
)
```

if you don't need the `rarbg` value you can skip the inner `()`

```
//         NAME  SEASON   EPISOE   MEDIUM  OPTIONS
$regex = '/(.+)\.S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)\.(.+)(\[.+\])?/i';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're so close, you just need to add the tests for the second half of the requirements:

```
(.*?).S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+).(.*?)-(.*?)\[(.*?)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/PfgMfq/1

Answer (score 1):

You should not need the /s modifier, it extends . to match meta chars and line breaks.
I would recommend to use the /e modifier to also allow lower case 's01e14'
Don't forget to escape the regex chars like . and [ with \. and \[

```
//         NAME  SEASON   EPISOE   MEDIUM  OPTIONS
$regex = '/(.+)\.S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)\.(.+)\[(.+)\]/i';
preg_match_all(
    $regex,
    $download,
    $posts,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

Test with '24.Legacy.S01E08.720p.HDTV.x264-AVS[rarbg]'

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24.Legacy.S01E08.720p.HDTV.x264-AVS[rarbg]
    [1] => 24.Legacy
    [2] => 01
    [3] => 08
    [4] => 720p.HDTV.x264-AVS
    [5] => rarbg
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write it down then :)

```
^
(?P<title>.+?)         # title
S(?P<season>\d+)       # season
E(?P<episode>\d+)\.    # episode
(?P<quality>[^-]+)-    # quality
(?P<type>[^[]+)        # type
\[
    (?P<torrent>[^]]+) # rest
\]
$
```

[**Demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zBm6mz/1/).